# Stating facts with past continuous

Tags: past-simple

When I just state a fact, I make no store is it possible to use the past continuous

I was working there for 5 months or only I worked there for 5 months is natural?

Comment: What do you mean by 'make no store'?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, both sentences are indicative and state a "fact" about the past.

The question is the wrong question!  You should not ask "Is it possible to use the past continuous?"   No speaker begins with "I want to use a particular type of grammar" and then thinks "what can I say with this grammar".

Instead start with "What do I want to say?", and then "What grammar would help me to express it?"

So what do you want to say? The meaning of "was working" is different to "worked" (the usual meaning of continuous aspects of verbs). So, which fact do you want to state?

Comment: Just my teacher told me that when I state a single fact I'm only allowed to use the past simple but I don't agree that's why I wrote here to ask you

Comment: It depends a bit on what you mean by a "fact".  Simple facts are best expressed with the simple past tense.   And that is probably the case here.  Unless you mean "was working" the normal past tense is "worked".

Comment: I do know that it is best to use the simple past but I want to know if the past continuous is correct too?